# Origin of rare Maltese surname De Nasi/Nasis?

Tags: surnames, malta

I am looking for help finding an etymology for the rare Maltese surname of De Nasi/Nasis.

I have done cursory research into this and surname, and many Maltese surnames now have etymologies, but this is one that I could not find any information on.

Comment: Charlie – if you could edit this question to be asking for authoritative references on determining the etymology of Maltese surnames, then it may be re-opened. Best to avoid questions on specific surnames, unless you detail and document your attempts to determine the etymology. The problem with most surname etymology questions on here is that they can often be easily "answered" by a Google search, but almost always the etymology is pure speculation unless extensive research is done into a particular name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75751/discussion-between-polygeo-and-pnuts).

Comment: I don’t know if this helps but Nasi means “Prince” or “President” in Hebrew.

Comment: In Google Books there are references to  de Nasis in Malta, apparently from Spain or Portugal.